# Is there a neutral element in IEEE754 with regards to addition

Tags: c, floating-point, double, ieee-754, low-level

Consider the following code snippet

```
double id = ?;
double res;
long unsigned *res_u = (long unsigned*)&res;

long unsigned i;
for (i = 0; i < (long unsigned)-1; i++){
    double *d1 = (double*)&i;
    res = id + *d1;
    assert(*res_u == i);
}
```

**My question**: Is there a value for `id`, so that the assertion holds for all `i`? In other words for the mathematicians among us: is there double that is the neutral element for addition?

Comment: Like 0 or -0 or NAN or Infinity or -Infinity?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan +inf + (-inf) makes NaN, so neither can be neutral.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is correct.  I was just trying to confirm the question.  Your -0 answer is nice.

Comment: I wrote “makes” in my answer where I had initially intended “==“ because technically, `-0. + (+0.) == -0.` is also true, not because of the behavior of `+` but because of the behavior of `==`, which is coarser than the equality of representations for zeroes. Conversely, `Nan + (-0.)` makes `NaN`, but these two sides are not equal for `==` although it is the name `NaN` on both sides. In this sense, there is no floating-point number such that `NaN + e == NaN`, but that's because there is no floating-point number equal to `NaN` for `==`, not because there is no `e` such that `NaN + e` makes `NaN`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-0.` is paradoxically the floating-point value that serves as neutral for addition.

`+0.` nearly is, but `-0. + (+0.)` makes `+0.`.

Apart from that, `+inf + (-0.)` makes `+inf`, `-inf + (-0.)` makes `-inf`, and `NaN + (-0.)` makes `NaN`.

Comment: Assuming default rounding.  If you set the rounding mode to round-to-minus-infinity, `+0.` is neutral.

Comment: What about normalization? Are you expecting anything weird to happen, when you do `r=d+(-0.)`?

Comment: @niklasfi: no normalization occurs when you add zero.

Comment: @niklasfi Well, if you are using a Flush-To-Zero architecture or a Denormals-Are-Zero one, adding either zero changes a subnormal into zero, so it is not neutral then. But you asked about IEEE 754, and IEEE 754 has no provisions for FTZ or DAZ (that I know of).

Comment: Right; DAZ and FTZ are outside the scope of IEEE-754.